# Tensorflow - pick values from indicies, what is the operation called?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

## An example

Suppose I have a tensor `values` with shape `(2,2,2)`

```
values = [[[0, 1],[2, 3]],[[4, 5],[6, 7]]]
```

And a tensor `indicies` with shape `(2,2)` which describes what values to be selected in the innermost dimension

```
indicies = [[1,0],[0,0]]
```

Then the result will be a `(2,2)` matrix with these values

```
result = [[1,2],[4,6]]
```

What is this operation called in tensorflow and how to do it?

## General

Note that the above shape `(2,2,2)` is only an example, it can be any dimension. Some conditions for this operation:

- `ndim(values) -1 = ndim(indicies)`
- `values.shape[:-1] == indicies.shape == result.shape`
- `indicies.max() < values.shape[-1] -1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can emulate this with `tf.gather_nd`. You will just have to convert "your" indices to a representation that is suitable for `tf.gather_nd`. The following example here is tied to your specific example, i.e. input tensors of shape `(2, 2, 2)` but I think this gives you an idea how you could write the conversion for input tensors with arbitrary shape, although I am not sure how easy it would be to implement this (haven't thought about it too long). Also, I'm not claiming that this is the easiest possible solution.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

values = np.array([[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[4, 5], [6, 7]]])
values_tf = tf.constant(values)
indices = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 0]])

converted_idx = []
for k in range(values.shape[0]):
    outer = []
    for l in range(values.shape[1]):
        inds = [k, l, indices[k][l]]
        outer.append(inds)
        print(inds)
    converted_idx.append(outer)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = tf.gather_nd(values_tf, converted_idx)
    print(sess.run(result))
```

This prints

```
[[1 2]
 [4 6]]
```

**Edit**: To handle arbitrary shapes here is a recursive solution that should work (only tested on your example):

```
def convert_idx(last_dim_vals, ori_indices, access_to_ori, depth):
    if depth == len(last_dim_vals.shape) - 1:
        inds = access_to_ori + [ori_indices[tuple(access_to_ori)]]
        return inds

    outer = []
    for k in range(ori_indices.shape[depth]):
        inds = convert_idx(last_dim_vals, ori_indices, access_to_ori + [k], depth + 1)
        outer.append(inds)
    return outer
```

You can use this together with the original code I posted like so:

```
...
converted_idx = convert_idx(values, indices, [], 0)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = tf.gather_nd(values_tf, converted_idx)
    print(sess.run(result))
```